# Can Js and Model.findAll() unable to display data in UI

Tags: canjs

I have this code where i am trying to retrieve data from model.findall() and display in UI as table

model.js

```
define(['jquery', 'can'], function ($, can) {
var serviceModel = can.Model.extend({
    findAll: function (params,servicename) {
         return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'data/+ servicename',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success ");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });

    }

}, {});
return serviceModel;
```

});

controller.js

```
            serviceModel.findAll(params,"SP_table", function(data) {
                if (data.status === "success") {
                    $('#idtable').dataTable().fnClearTable();
                    $('#idtable').dataTable().fnAddData(data.result);
                }else{
                    alert("inside alert");
                }
            });
```

issue is in serviceModel.findAll() i am unable to get data inside serviceModel.findAll() because data is in the form of stored procedure or macro, which i am getting using "servicename" from function above
please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the raw xhr data from the ajax call and convert it to an appropriate format by overriding the parseModels method:

https://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.parseModels.html

> Overwriting parseModels If your service returns data like:
>
> { thingsToDo: [{name: "dishes", id: 5}] } You will want to overwrite
>   parseModels to pass the models what it expects like:
>
> Task = can.Model.extend({  parseModels: function(data){    return
>   data.thingsToDo;  } },{}); You could also do this like:
>
> Task = can.Model.extend({  parseModels: "thingsToDo" },{});
>   can.Model.models passes each instance's data to can.Model.model to
>   create the individual instances.

In their example above, the response is a nested JSON: in yours, it is your procedure or macro. You have the opportunity here in parseModels to rewrite the response in the appropriate format.